# Creating a LiveData class for my ViewModel class and Retrofit class

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I'm struggling with creating a `LiveData` class for my `ViewModel` class and my `Retrofit` class that makes API calls.

`ViewModel` class:

```
class ApiViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private lateinit var status: String

    @NonNull
    fun getApiResults(param1: String, param2: String, param3: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                val listResult = ApiCalls.retrofitService.ApiCallsService(param1, param2, param3)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                status = "Failure: ${e.message}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Retrofit` class:

```
private const val BASE_URL = "https://sampleapiurl.com"

private val moshi = Moshi.Builder().addLast(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory()).build()

private val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build()

private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .client(client)
    .build()

interface ApiCallsService {
    @GET(".")
    suspend fun apiCalls(
        @Query("param1") param1: String,
        @Query("param2") param2: String,
        @Query("param3") param3: String
    ): Call<CustomDataClass>
}

object ApiCalls {
    val retrofitService: ApiCallsService by lazy { retrofit.create(ApiCallsService::class.java) }
}
```

Now, inside the `try catch` statement in my `ViewModel` class, I want to pass the result of `listResult` into a `LiveData` class. That way in my `onViewCreated` in my fragments, I can do something like this to retrieve the data:

```
val apiViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(ApiViewModel::class.java)
apiViewModel.getApiResults("val1", "val2", "val3").observe(...
```

How should my `LiveData` class look so I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to create LiveData to observe any values you desired. In your case, seems you need to observe the value of `status` and `listResult`. Therefore, I suggest you create LiveData in `ApiViewModel`, i.e.

```
val statusLiveData = MutableLiveData<String>()
val listResultLiveData = MutableLiveData<YourListType>()
```

and post value to it in your `getApiResults()` (modify your `getApiResults()`)

```
@NonNull
fun getApiResults(param1: String, param2: String, param3: String) {
     viewModelScope.launch {
         try {
           listResultLiveData.postValue(ApiCalls.retrofitService.ApiCallsService(param1, param2, param3))
         } catch (e: Exception) {
            statusLiveData.postValue("Failure: ${e.message}")
         }
     }
}
```

and add this to `onViewCreated()` in the Fragment

```
apiViewModel.statusLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { 
   // TODO: What to do with the status            
})
apiViewModel.listResultLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { 
   // TODO: What to do on get list result            
})
```

Comment: This is almost perfect, but there is one issue. I included a `Log.d` statement to print the results inside the `statusLiveData.observe` block and I noticed when I make an API call for the first time, the `Log.d` gets printed once. But, when I make an API call a second, third, fourth, etc. time, it prints the result from my previous API call and then prints the result of the current API call twice, thus printing three times. How do I fix this? Is there a way to clear the `LiveData` inside `ViewModel` before making a call to `Retrofit`?

Comment: Pretty sure `observe()` will only triggered only on `postValue()` called, I'm not sure about the value returned passed in `postValue()`, but can you help to update your question by attach the code where you put the `Log.d()` and how you call `postValue()`?

Comment: My mistake, Before, I was making another call to the API instead of using the `Observer`'s `it` value parameter, which already has the results.